# Insert text to selected range with button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I apologize in advance for having little to no knowledge on this matter. I am familiar enough to utilize VBA but have recently made the switch to Sheets and I am lost.

I was originally looking for a way to prompt a drop down menu when double clicking a cell in a range that will then add the selected information as a prefix to the text.

**Example**: cell contains "First Last", upon double clicking you get a drop down to select "Mr., Mrs." when selecting "Mr." the cell now says "Mr. First Last" but it doesn't appear that you can set a double click event.

So now I am trying to come up with another solution where you select desired cells and 'apply' the function.

**Example**: Select cells A1 B1 C3 D9, click a button that applies "Mr. " as a prefix. Selecting it again will remove it.

Please help me get this moving.

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge of Javascript is so poor I didn't post my efforts as it's going to end up and make things more confusing for everyone... But I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// menu

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⚡ Scripts')
  .addItem(' Add Mr', 'add_Mr')
  .addItem('Remove Mr', 'remove_Mr')
  .addToUi();
}


// functions

function add_Mr() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i in ranges) {
    var data = ranges[i].getValues();
    for (var row in data) for (var col in data[row])
      if (data[row][col] != '') data[row][col] = 'Mr. ' + data[row][col];
    ranges[i].setValues(data);
  }
}

function remove_Mr() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i in ranges) {
    var data = ranges[i].getValues();
    for (var row in data) for (var col in data[row])
      if (data[row][col] != '') data[row][col] = data[row][col].replace(/^Mr\. /,'');
    ranges[i].setValues(data);
  }
}
```

It will add menu Scripts and two commands 'Add Mr' and 'Remove Mrs' for selected cells.

[image]

And as a homework you can try to add `add_Mrs()` and `remove_Mrs()` functions.

If you need to toggle 'Mr' here you go:

```
function toggle_Mr() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i in ranges) {
    var data = ranges[i].getValues();
    for (var row in data) for (var col in data[row]) {
        var cell = data[row][col];
        if (cell == '') continue;                      // if empty --> go to next cell
        if (cell.match(/^Mr\. /)) {                    // if contains 'Mr.'
          data[row][col] = cell.replace(/^Mr\. /,'');  // --> remove 'Mr.'
          continue;                                    // --> go to next cell
        } else {
          data[row][col] = 'Mr. ' + data[row][col];    // else --> add 'Mr.'
        }
    }
    ranges[i].setValues(data);
  }
}
```

**Update**

Here is the same function `toggle_Mr()` with example how you can get the 'coordinates' of all processed cells:

```
function toggle_Mr() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selection = sheet.getSelection();
  var ranges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  for (var i in ranges) {

    // get 'coordinates' (col, row) of first (left-top) cell of selected range
    var start_col = ranges[i].getColumn(); 
    var start_row = ranges[i].getRow();
    
    var data = ranges[i].getValues();

    for (var row in data) for (var col in data[row]) {
      var cell = data[row][col];

      // calculate the real 'coordinates' of processed cells
      var real_col = +start_col + +col;
      var real_row = +start_row + +row
      console.log('Process the cell [' + real_col + '][' + real_row + ']');
      
      if (cell == '') continue;
      if (cell.match(/^Mr\. /)) {
        data[row][col] = cell.replace(/^Mr\. /,'');
        continue;
      } else {
        data[row][col] = 'Mr. ' + data[row][col];
      }
    }
    ranges[i].setValues(data);
  }
}
```

You can see the cell 'coordinates' in console if you run the function from the Script Editor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I played around with it for an hour trying to figure out how to make it toggle-able, then came back to see you posted it. So I got my homework in and learned quite a bit with your post saving my frustration last second :) If I were to insert an image from a URL to the right side of the cell can you point me towards an example of that? I can insert the image, but not specify it being relative to a cell.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know the answer. I don't even know if it's possible at all (if I understand your goal right). I just googled it with no luck. It makes sense to post the new question. And I'll be curious to know the answer as well.

Comment: I was able to get an image to embed at the desired location, so I guess from your script above can you explain a few things? How do I obtain the column and row from each loop for more use? [col][row] doesn't seem to work as parameters. Why is (/^Mr\. /) So funky? Why can't you just say ('Mr.')? Are ranges stored in an array? Is that what [I] represents? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, Kevin. `/^Mr\. /` is a RegularExpression. `^` means start of the string. `\.` means a dot. The dots is escaped because a dot means any symbol in RegExp. Actually for this particular case you could use just `'Mr.'`. RegExp's aren't necessary in this case. I used it automatically. Since usually it has some benefits. Say if, hypothetically, there will be 'First Mr. Name' the simply replace 'Mr.' gives wrong result. But, of course, it's a weird name.

Comment: `[col]` and `[row]` in the code mean columns and rows. But they are 'local' columns and rows of the ranges. Not the 'global' columns and rows of the sheet. You can get the real 'global' columns and rows from these [col] and [row] but it will need additional coding. I think you can get 'first column' or 'first row' of any range and add [col] or [row] to it respectively.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Note: `+col` is a short for `Number(col)` — to convert a string into a number. Because the 'col' and 'row' are strings in this case.